# ESP8266 not turning light on d5 pin

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

Basically I have a program which reads data and if its a 1 itll turn the onboard led on (which it does and say on on the serial monitor. Although,I have set it so that d5 should output and I'm using an led to test it and it doens't light up? I have taken out some code eg. the API keys and my router info so that's why it isn't there.

```
    #include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ThingSpeak.h>

//school
const char* ssid = "";
const char* pass = "";




char* thingSpeakAddress = "api.thingspeak.com";
//This is for channel for temp
unsigned long channelID = 1029606;
unsigned int dataFieldOne = 1; 
char* apiWriteKey = 
char* apiReadKey = 


//This is for the fan stats channel
unsigned long channelID2 = 1371231;
unsigned int dataFieldOne2 = 1; 
char* apiWriteKey2 = 
char* apiReadKey2 = 
int x = 1;

//dht stuff
#define DHTPIN 0
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHT11);

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  dht.begin();
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("Connecting to..");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  delay(500);

  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  while(WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(".");

  
  }

  
  Serial.print("SSID......");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  Serial.println("NodeMCU successfully connected to WiFi...");

  Serial.print("IP Address allocated to NodeMCU ESP8266... ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.print("MAC Address of ESP8266... ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  WiFi.printDiag(Serial);
  ThingSpeak.begin( client );
}  

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  
    
      

  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  if (isnan(t))
  {
    Serial.println("failed to read from dht sensor!");
    return;
  }

  writeTSData(1029606,1,t);
  
 //writeTSData(channelID, dataFieldOne, x );
 
    if (readTSData(channelID2, dataFieldOne2)==1){
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
      digitalWrite(14,LOW);
      Serial.print("ON");
    }
    else{

      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
      digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
      Serial.print("OFF");
      
    }
  delay(5000);
}




// Use this function if you want to write a single field
int writeTSData( long TSChannel, unsigned int TSField, int data ){
  int  writeSuccess = ThingSpeak.writeField( TSChannel, TSField, data, apiWriteKey ); // Write the data to the channel
  if ( writeSuccess ){
    
    Serial.println( String(data) + " written to Thingspeak." );
    }
    
    return writeSuccess;
}

float readTSData( long TSChannel2,unsigned int TSField2 ){
    
  float data =  ThingSpeak.readFloatField( TSChannel2, TSField2, apiWriteKey2 );
  Serial.println( " Data read from ThingSpeak: " + String( data, 9 ) );
  return data;
  
}
```

Comment: did you try it with the Blink sketch?

Comment: Agreed with Juraj. Go back to the basics and try a blink example with that pin as the output.

Comment: I managed to get it working somehow, I think It was a wiring issue sorry for the trouble.